# How to move, change the width of a rectangle contained within a border

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Please tell me about WPF, Binding, MVVM, I have 2 problems:

1. Click on the other rectangle and drag it left and right within the
   border containing it.
2. To mouse over the right edge of the rectangle, click and drag to
   change its width. Please guide me.

Image of my software interface here:

[image: Image of my software interface]

Here is a small code of 1 border, as shown I have 2 borders and 1 timeline:

```
<Border x:Name="BoderN" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5" AllowDrop="True">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HuNLst}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="StackN" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 1 0" Background="White">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".7">
                        <Grid x:Name="gridElement" Width="{Binding Duration}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectOuter" Fill="Blue" Opacity=".3" />
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

Comment: Help me! Thank you very much

Comment: Your post contains two questions, however as explained in [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/344280), the format for questions here is one question per post.  You're much more likely to get help here if you follow that format and also provide a [mcve] showing what you have done so far.  You might also check out [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, both pages have tips for writing stack overflow questions that are more likely to get an answer.